# OpenCv SVMligh error. "writing alpha file... _____________ no such file or directory

Tags: file, opencv, alpha, svmlight

I am running my project and getting this error (http://prntscr.com/2021uq):

[image]

I am using OpenCV 2,46 SVM Light created on 11. Mai 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using GITHUB's "trainHog" (?).
svm learn main.c has following code.

strcpy (learn_parm->alphafile, "");

try to use that in your code (Where you defined learning parameters)